# SSH message, source of a after-login greeting command

Tags: ssh, sshd

On a server previously adminstered by someone else i noticed non-standard after-login ssh message. It looks like this:

```
In case of problems please send an email to ....@.....

Disk quotas for user ***** (uid 1234):
Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
/dev/mapper/asasdf  6094452  2147483648 2147483648          365672       0       0
```

The first part, "In case of ...." is in the `/etc/motd`.
But the second, quota, is the hard part. I don't know where it came from. I checked:

1. `/etc/motd`
2. `sshd_config`, Banner is set to `none`, there is no `ForceCommand`
3. `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, nothing relevant.

How this effect could be achieved?

EDIT: Distribution is PLD-Linux

Best Regards,
Kamil

Comment: Which OS? `/etc/update-motd.d` might be relevant as well.

Comment: @muru, PLD-Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the profile files?

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
/etc/bashrc
/etc/profile
```

The previous admin could have left that `quota` part as his custom shell login.

Comment: I found someting in /etc/profile.d/local.sh, but this message is seen by each user after login, displaying his/her quota status. Will this file be executed for each user?

Comment: Heh, it will. In `man` it says that `/etc/profile` calls scripts in `profile.d`. I didn't knew that output of such initialization could be seen after SSH login. But it runs `/etc/profile.d/local.sh` for a logging in user, checking his quotas?

Comment: Lol yeah, think `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc` as 'global' settings. Glad you found it.